# How to change "styles." file extension in Angular 2 project?

Tags: css, angular, styles, angular-cli

I created an Angular 2 project but I forgot to create the styles file with .scss extension. I typed;

```
ng new my-project
```

instead of typing;

```
ng new my-project --style=scss
```

So now my styles file has .css extension. How can I change it to .scss with a right way? When I change it in the folder I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been changed for angular cli version 6. Now when generating a new project type:

```
ng new sassy-project --style=scss
```

To change an existing project generating with angular cli version 6+ in the angular.json file you can update the project[projectName].schematics object to look like this:

```
"projects": {
  "sassy-project: {
    ...
    "schematics": {
      "@schmatics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To update it using the Angular CLI use:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular cli is bundling your project according to his configuration.

So in order to use a css pre-processor, you should also tell angular cli to do so.

Change in `angular-cli.json` (or since beta 33 `.angular-cli.json`) :

```
{
  ...

  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

To

```
{
  ...

  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "sccs", (or whatever extension you want)
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 6+, the `ng set` command has been deprecated. 
You need to use the `ng config` command instead. Here is how to change to scss using the `ng config`

```
ng config defaults.styleExt=scss
```

If you are getting the Error `Value cannot be found`, try this command instead.

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

You could also change it manually in the angular.json file. [See Braden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441485/5784924)

Note that thoses command have been taken directly from [this source](https://medium.com/@ngubanethabo.ambrose/migrate-from-css-to-scss-stylesheets-for-existing-angular-application-d61f8061f5b7)